# Using Umbraco with Subfolders

Tags: iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I have built an Umbraco project (7.2.2) on my local machine and it all works well. I now want to copy it to our test server running IIS 7.5.

I have created a Virtual Folder in IIS under the default web site and copied the project across. The url I am using is www.ourserver.com/testumbraco. I can access the content ok but if I try to login to edit the content I get a blank page (umbraco#/login/false) and shortly afterwards it returns to the login page with Session timed out.

If I Inspect the page I can see that some resources have failed to load with Error 404. It is looking for www.ourserver.com/umbraco and not www.ourserver.com/testumbraco/umbraco.

Is there a configuration setting I need to change to make this work properly?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `umbracoPath` setting in the [web.config](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/webconfig7)

Comment: I just submitted a pull request on github to update the documentation.  It might take a few days before the page is updated.  Depending on when (and if) the pull request is accepted.